# Calculate percentage to total using rowPercents

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate a percentage to total for, lets say, the following reproducible example:

```
structure(c(197.95, 197.95, 197.95, 186.8, 190.51, 195.16, 199.81, 
202.59, 202.59, 202.59, 92.28, 92.28, 90.07, 89.82, 87.36, 87.61, 
90.56, 89.82, 90.07, 89.82, 20.43, 20.43, 20.43, 20.43, 20.43, 
20.43, 20.43, 20.43, 20.43, 20.64, 24.7, 24.95, 24.54, 23.97, 
23.97, 24.38, 24.38, 24.38, 24.54, 24.54, 37.4, 37.4, 37.4, 35.43, 
35.43, 35.43, 35.43, 35.43, 35.43, 39.37, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 16.05, 
16.05, 16.05, 16.05, 15.62, 15.62, 16.05, 15.62, 15.62, 15.62, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), index = structure(c(470620800, 
470880000, 470966400, 471052800, 471139200, 471225600, 471484800, 
471571200, 471657600, 471744000), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .indexCLASS = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tclass = "Date", tzone = "UTC", class = c("xts", 
"zoo"), .Dim = c(10L, 9L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("AVON", "BA.", 
"CMRG", "COB", "MGGT", "QQ.", "RR.", "SNR", "ULE")))
```

I need to return the same presentation of my data but each value is a percentage of the total of the row it belongs to. I did a lot of research and tried `prop.table` which returns a `subscript` error and finally I used `rowPercents` which is part of `RcmdrMisc` package. However, I could not find how to let it ignore the `NA` in my data set.

In the example provides there are two whole columns of `NA`. I can not drop them as the whole data set has some values for the subsequent rows.

Note the the class of my example is `zoo` and `xts`

Comment: @Gregor Great, it does the job and it is very simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any external packages for this.

```
dat.percent <- dat / rowSums(dat, na.rm = T) * 100
```

Check that it works:

```
> all(abs(rowSums(dat.percent, na.rm = T) - 100) < 0.0001)
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

`prop.table` does not seem to work with xts/zoo objects but this works:

```
library(xts)

prop.table(coredata(x), 1)
```

It returns all NAs which is correct since there is an NA in each row (and it is impossible to calculate the proportions without knowing every value). If you want to regard the NA values as zero then:

```
prop.table( na.fill(coredata(x), 0), 1)
```